# You're in a room and your child is standing outside in the living room. Why do some native teachers say "come/get in here" is wrong?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage

You're in a room and your child is standing outside in the living room. You say to the child "**come/get in here**".

Some native teachers say ["come/get in here" is wrong](https://www.quora.com/Youre-in-a-room-and-your-child-is-standing-outside-in-the-living-room-Are-they-natural-to-say-to-the-child-get-here-over-here-in-here-come-here-over-here-in-here-get-your-ass-here-over-here-in-here-bring-your-ass) in this situation, **why is that?**

Answer (score 4):

"Come in here." and "Get in here" are completely natural, when you mean into a room, or into the house. If someone said it's wrong, you should probably ask them why they think so.

Comment: The question in the linked Quora article is phrased with a lot of slashed either/or options which may have some ambiguous readings; but for any intended expansion of them that I can see, all are grammatically correct and reasonably idomatic, at various levels of formality, notwithstanding that well-credentialed responder's broad statement otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

"Come here" is plain and direct.

You can soften it by phrasing as a question.  "Could you come here?"

Equally often you can ask a person to come just by calling their name.

"Get in here" is assertive to the point of being rude.  Sometimes this is intended.

You would say "get in here" when you are very angry with your child and they are being rude and disrespectful and you lose your temper.  Please go to parenting stack exchange to discuss if this is ever appropriate behaviour for an adult.

The question really is, do you want to be rude to your children?

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of the *imperative*, used to give commands and orders.

In English, the form of the verb used for the imperative is the base form of the main verb, which is used without a subject: the subject of a command, order, or suggestion — you, the person being directed — is usually left out of the sentence and is said to be the *understood* subject. For instance:

- [You] Hurry up or I'll leave you behind!
- Before trying to assemble the furniture from Ikea, [you] read these instructions carefully.

In this case, the sentence could be rewritten as: "You come in here!"

The verb *get* has so many meanings - I've counted about 33 - that it can be difficult to sort them out. It can mean the same as 'come,' 'go,' or 'to make progress eventually or with some difficulty.' It can also mean, 'to go after, take hold of, and bring (something) for one's own or for another's purposes; fetch."

In the example, it means either basically the same as 'come,' or it means 'bring.' If it's interpreted as 'bring' in the example "Get in here," what's being left out is the subject AND object: you. As in "[You] Come in here," it's the subject, but 'you' is also the subject, in the form of a reflexive pronoun: *yourself*.

A reflexive pronoun is a special kind of pronoun, usually used when the object of a sentence is the same as the subject.

So, you can rewrite the second example - *Get in here* - as, "You [subject] get yourself [object] in here!"

Note the use of an exclamation point, usually referred to as an exclamation *mark* in the UK. It should be used carefully, but using it with an imperative is perfectly correct. And if it's a teacher issuing the command to a student, it definitely needs an exclamation point!

Here are some useful links:

[Guide to Grammar - Sentence Subjects](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/subjects.htm)

[Antimoon - you vs. Yourself](http://www.antimoon.com/forum/t9714.htm)

[Collins Dictionary - The Imperative](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/the-imperative)

[Dictionary.com - Get](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/get?s=t)

[Grammerly.com - Exclamation mark](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/exclamation-mark/)

Comment: Grammer? Sentance?

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out - I'm a terrible speller. That's probably why the answer got voted down... :(

Comment: @Michael Harvey - next time feel free to correct my spelling directly if you wish.

Comment: So, imperative is not the present simple tense, isn't it? For example, you and your friend are in the room, the boy is outside in the living room. Do we say "The boy come in here!" or "The boy comeS in here"?

Comment: We would say "Come in here, boy!" (or, more likely, use his name). _The boy comes in here_ is a statement, not an imperative!